# Post not passing parameters as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So, basically when I submit a form, I'm getting this error: `"param is missing or the value is empty: client"`. Then, I tried to debug it and I see that my hash with parameters is not passing like: `"clients" => { "name" => "foobar", etc etc }`. You guys can see an example below.

Everything in my controller and in my form is set up correctly, so I have no idea what's going on. Could you guys please help me?

`{"authenticity_token"=>"st1pw5zaEEpVD33vRizImaVaZfl59PezZWLF791yQSPwARGuFmJyeDkL41t/svGFNRfi9anYhjK3wkVkNWpFHQ==", "name"=>"Test", "surname"=>"test", "birth_date"=>"1995-05-30", "description"=>"test", "commit"=>"Adicionar", "controller"=>"clients", "action"=>"create"}`

**EDIT**

form:

```
<%= form_with(model: @client, local: true, html: { 'data-model' => 'client' }, class: "formInput") do |form| %>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= form.label :name, 'Nome' %>
              <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= form.label :surname, 'Sobrenome: ' %>
              <%= form.text_field :surname, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= form.label :birth_date, 'Data de nascimento: ' %>
              <%= form.date_field :birth_date, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :description, 'Descrição' %>
          <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label "Imagem", 'Imagem' %>
          <%= form.file_field :avatar, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= form.submit 'Adicionar', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def create
 @client = Client.new(client_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @client.save
    format.html { redirect_to action: "index" }
    flash[:success] = "Cliente foi criado."
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: The controller and the form code would really help.

Comment: @KaomTe edited w/ controller and form.

Comment: @frosassss Strange!.  have you initialized:@client in the new action of clients_controller?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely just need to create an instance of `Client` in the `new` action of your controller...

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
end
```

Another way to test would be to just do this explicitly in the view if that doesn't work for whatever reason...

```
<%= form_with(model: Client.new, local: true, html: { 'data-model' => 'client' }, class: "formInput") do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be absolutely certain because you didn't post all of your controller code, but I suspect in your controller code you have something like:

```
  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, :birthdate, :surname, :other_stuff)
  end
```

This means your client parameters should be in a hash within the params hash keyed under the symbol :client.

Make sure your @client is actually an instance of class Client.